# jquery ui draggable divs jump around when dynamic content changes

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'd like to use jquery UI's draggable objects in a page where the content changes dynamically.  Unfortunately, when the content of one div changes, the other divs often get moved around as well.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Ideally, I'd like for any snapped relationships to continue to hold after content changes.  Failing that, it'd be great if the div positions simply ignored changes in the sizes of other divs.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z73Nb/) where you can see what I mean.

Comment: Just to clarify. You want the position of all the boxes to be static but the size of them to change. so when one gets bigger there is an overlay between the two divs?

Comment: The perfect solution would be to preserve snapped relationships.  So if div A's top left corner is snapped to B's top right corner, they stay that way after a resize.  A second best solution would be for no div to move when the content of another div changes, i.e. a change in A's content never causes a change in B's location.  Both of these seem like reasonably intuitive interfaces.  The first is a little more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to position: absolute the divs, not have them relative. You would then need to have the container relatively positioned to keep the divs inside them have their positions relative to the container.

CSS update:

```
#container{
    width:600px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:20px;
    position: relative;
}
.box{
    width:50%;
    padding:20px;
    border:2px solid black;
    position:absolute;
}​
```

There are other issues that you'll need to figure out. Upon the first render, the two boxes will overlap. You'll need to have the top/left css values predefined to stop them from overlapping initially. Either this will be done with the html (you'll have to know the height beforehand) or with javascript (you could experience snapping if it takes a bit to load all at once).

**Warning.** I don't think absolutely positioned divs is considered a good practice, generally. You might want to explain what you're trying to do and, if applicable, a better solution could be found. This answer might do what you want, but depending on how you're using it will determine if you probably should. If its for layout, it can get pretty maintenance heavy as you have to reposition everything to fit again. Each div box inside the container would be positioned absolutely and ignore each other. Positioning child items relative to the parent like a custom button or menu that follows the div is a good use of absolutely positioned items.

Comment: Good question. The page I'm designing has several "panes" containing tools for interacting with an otherwise static text document.  In terms of screen real estate, there is one large document and several smaller panes.  The size and usefulness of the various panes will vary, so making them draggable (and collapsible) makes sense.  Think of the interface for adobe photoshop -- my use case is quite similar.